Why do Chrome DevTools for cached requests show responses from other requests?
After caching, chrome developer tools shows responses from other requests.
Before caching:

GET http://localhost:8080/redirect1


Response: 301 -> http://localhost:8080/redirect2


GET http://localhost:8080/redirect2


Response: 302 -> http://localhost:8080/redirect3


GET http://localhost:8080/redirect3


Response: 307 -> http://localhost:8080/echo


GET http://localhost:8080/echo


Response: 200

After caching:

GET http://localhost:8080/redirect1


Response: 302 -> http://localhost:8080/redirect3 - WHY???


GET http://localhost:8080/redirect2


Response: 307 -> http://localhost:8080/echo  - WHY???


GET http://localhost:8080/redirect3


Response: 200   - WHY???


GET http://localhost:8080/echo


Response: 200

Chrome Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Reproducing steps

Create nginx.conf:

events {}
http {    
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location /echo {
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
            return 200 "URI: $uri\nArgs: $args\n";
        }

        location /redirect1 {
            return 301 $scheme://$http_host/redirect2;
        }

        location /redirect2 {
            return 302 $scheme://$http_host/redirect3;
        }

        location /redirect3 {
            return 307 $scheme://$http_host/echo;
        }
    }
}


Run nginx:

docker run --rm -it -v nginx__echo.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -p 8080:80 nginx:latest

Open link 2 times: http://localhost:8080/redirect1

